# vim-plug error on Windows

Tags: vim-windows, plugin-vim-plug

Longtime Linux, vim and vim-plug user, setting things up on Windows for the first time.

For debugging, I've reduced my .vimrc to just this:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'lifepillar/vim-solarized8'
call plug#end()
```

But PlugInstall gives me this:

[image]

I've verified that `C:\Users\jeff\vimfiles\plugged` exists, and I can write in that directory just fine from vim, e.g. `:w C:\Users\jeff\vimfiles\plugged\foo.txt`.

Ideas on what might be wrong, or how to get additional debugging info out of vim-plug would be appreciated!

Comment: That seems correct. Do you have a file named `vim-solarized8` in the `plugged` folder?

Comment: if this doesn't work, you can manually clone it into that directory

Comment: PlugInstall should do a git clone and create that directory -- at least that how it works on Linux. Is that not true on Windows?

Comment: Try `:debug PlugInstall` (I keep `:help :debug` open in a separate Vim when I do this)